# Describe the elemnt in $Q (a^{1/ n}, w) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Describe the element in $Q (a^{  1/ n}, w)$ where $w=\exp ((2\pi i )/n )$

The basis of

$Q (a^{ 1/ n}, w) $= 
${(1, a^{  1/ n}, ...,(a^{ 1/ n})^{n-1}, 
   w,w^2,.....w^{n-1}, 
a^{ 1/n} w ,a^{1/ }w^2 ,....,{a^{  1/ n}}^{n-1} w^{n-1}, ....
.
{a^{  1/ n}}^{n-1}w^{n-1}})$

Is it true ? 
 If not, what is the correct solution? 
Thanks in advance.